# Formated xfs partition to ext4 by mistake, can it be recovered?

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, xfs

I formatted a xfs partition by mistake to ext4. Can this be undone and the data recovered?

Actually, I did not chose to have the partition reformatted during installation, I just kept the default partition type ext4, when I should have selected xfs, so I do not know if the installer reformatted it or just changed the partition type. I'll give a try to testdisk since I now have cloned the drive with dd.

Answer (score 1):

Testdisk couldn't do anything. I was able to use photorec to restore the data, music files mostly, and using Musicbrainz Picard I was able to then rename the restored file automatically.